# List with a key

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, list, c#-3.0, dictionary

Before I embark on writing my own, is there a List like construct that also contains a Dictionary like key?

And before someone suggests using a Dictionary instead, the order of items is important to me and Dictionary cannot guarantee a position.

So, I'd like to be able to retrieve the item in the following manner:

```
int position = 4;
MyObject o = MyCollection[position];
```

and like this:

```
string key = "MyKey";
MyObject o = MyCollection[key];
```

Is there some such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can use the [Ordered Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) class for this.

In fact, yes.  Yes you can.

Comment: Non-generic.  Feels dirty. But it'll probably do.